# How to filter queryset value in one of the form fields using CreateView?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

My task is to change the value of one field in the form (drop-down list with Foreignkey connection). I need to exclude the values of technology that the user already has. 
I use CreateView and ModelForm.

**forms.py**

```
class SkillCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(SkillCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       employee_current_technology = Technology.objects.filter(??? --- How can I get editing user pk ????-----)
       self.fields['technology'].queryset = Technology.objects.exclude(name__in=employee_current_technology)
```

I know that somehow I can get pk from url using kwarg and get_form_kwarg values, but I can't figure out how to do that.

**urls.py**

```
   path('profile/<int:pk>/skill/create/', SkillCreateView.as_view(), name='skill_create'),
```

**views.py**

```
class SkillCreateView(AuthorizedMixin, CreateView):
    """
    Create new course instances
    """
    model = Skill
    form_class = SkillCreateForm
    template_name = 'employee_info_create.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(SkillCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        Employee.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']) -->get me pk
        ????
        return kwargs

    .....
```

**models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """Employee information."""
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee')
    summary = models.TextField("summary", blank=True, default='')
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(
        Technology, through="Skill", verbose_name="skills", blank=True)


class Skill(models.Model):
    """Information about an employee's skills."""

    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employee_skills")
    technology = models.ForeignKey(Technology, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Technology(models.Model):
    """Technologies."""
    tech_set = models.ForeignKey(Skillset, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="skillset")
    name = models.CharField('technology name', max_length=32, unique=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Techgroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="group")
```

Comment: Can you provide the related models (`Technology` and `Employee`)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the `pk` in the form, like:

```
class SkillCreateView(AuthorizedMixin, CreateView):
    """
    Create new course instances
    """
    model = Skill
    form_class = SkillCreateForm
    template_name = 'employee_info_create.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(employee_pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return kwargs
```

You can then update the queryset in the form like:

```
class SkillCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, employee_pk=None, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       if employee_pk is not None:
           self.fields['technology'].queryset = Technology.objects.exclude(
               skill__employee_id=employee_pk
           )
```

Comment: Willem, you're right as always, thank you very much.